# How to quickly know number of elements in a class after classify in ArcGIS Pro like ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

How to quickly know number of elements in a class after classify in ArcGIS Pro like ArcMap 10.7?

[image: Elements in Class in Arc Map 10.7]

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool in ArcGISPro called [Frequency](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/analysis/frequency.htm) that will return a table with the counts of unique values in an attribute table.

There is a tool called [Get Count](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) that will return the total number of items in a feature class.

Comment: Op deals with classification of continious data, so it's not about frequency ot unique values